# How to use a bit complex object as a value of a key in localStorage of Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension that would feed data in the `localStorage` of the form:

```
var a = 'YouTube';
var data = {
    'title': 'twenty one pilots: Stressed Out [OFFICIAL VIDEO]',
    'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXRviuL6vMY'
};
localStorage.setItem(a, data);
```

But when I look into the resources in dev. tools, it doesn't show the `data` object in the value table. How can I make it appear in there?What's wrong with the code?
[The Image of the console and the localStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCSRy.png).

I have tried commands like `localStorage.YouTube` and `localStorage.getItem('YouTube')` but it always returns `[object Object]`.

What could be a possible workaround for making something like this possible?

Comment: You may want to switch to asynchronous [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) that supports object values directly.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for sharing that. Can we see the key-value pairs of `chrome.storage` in the dev-tools?

Comment: yep: [Inspect chrome.storage.sync while debugging Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32471596)

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage in HTML5 can only store key-values strings. You can't store objects there.

BUT, you can use JSON. To make a string from your object you can use `JSON.stringify(yourObj);`
and when you want to get value from LocalStorage you simply parse that string and create new object which you can use again. `JSON.parse(yourObj);`