# Retrieving SVG image from website

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to retrieve an SVG image, store it locally, and use it later in the popup.js. The retrieval is done by a content script:

```
   var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
        chrome.storage.local.set({'svg': svg}, function() {
            console.log(svg.localName === "svg"); //returns true
        });
```

Unfortunately, the popup seems to get nothing but an empty object.

```
chrome.storage.local.get("svg", function(svg) {
                console.log(svg.localName === "svg"); //returns false
});
```

I have little to no experience with Javascript and Chrome extensions, so I am probably doing something very stupid here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.storage` is for JSON-ifiable objects, not for the complex class instances like DOM elements. To inspect the storage use [Storage Area Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32471596/3959875) extension.

In your case, store the outer HTML:

```
var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
chrome.storage.local.set({svg: svg.outerHTML});
```

Then recreate the element from the HTML:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('svg', data => {
    var tmp = document.createElement('div');
    tmp.innerHTML = data.svg;
    var svg = tmp.firstElementChild;
    document.body.appendChild(svg);
});
```

or

```
chrome.storage.local.get('svg', data => {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data.svg);
});
```

Advanced tip: when storing *a lot* of HTML/text in chrome.storage, consider using [LZstring](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string).