# Store data into chrome.storage.sync through Console for a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it possible to insert values into Chrome's Local Storage API `chrome.storage.sync` through a Console or any other way?

I think this can be a security issue if it's possible.

Comment: Sure, just open [devtools on an extension page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982) and run chrome.storage.sync.set({foo: 'bar'}) and so on. There's also [Storage Area Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32471596). There's no "security issue" here.

Comment: @wOxxOm yep tried it & it works. so follow up how to implement licenses in chrome extension because one extension got broke because of this?

Comment: aah I think it was developers fault. developer was setting state in frontend to check if user has downloaded. I think IAP should mitigate this or creating custom user accounts of paid users