# My Chrome extension writes to local storage: why can't I see or delete the data in Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

Pretty simple storage, just one string being saved into local storage:

```
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        'current_lookup_details': 'a string'
    });
```

which I get with

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('current_lookup_details', function(result) {...})
```

but I wanted to clear it, while developing, and according to dev tools it's not there. Nothing appears in the Application tab, Local Storage, or any of the other storage options.

[image]

This is true in my background.html and my options page as well. It doesn't seem to be there and I can't clear it.

If I remove the extension from Chrome, and re-add it, the data is gone. But that's the only way I can remove it.

Do extensions have some special form of storage not accessible to the Dev Tools?

Comment: The API documentation is just bad, it uses a misleading name for the storage. Devtools doesn't support it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32471596/) for a solution.

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed answer my question, all good and I'm inspecting away. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb is the TLDR.