# Place an Object within Object within Chrome chrome.storage.sync.set for Data Set

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

How do I place an Object within an Object within chrome.storage.sync.set

The outcome I'm needing is, so I can then search the Value and then pull the data like name and path

```
0:ID {
Name: Name of file
Path: Path Location
Enabled: true
}
1:ID{
Name: Name of file
Path: Path Location
Enabled: true
}
2:ID{
Name: Name of file
Path: Path Location
Enabled: true
}
```

I've used

```
var save = {};
save.id = {};
save.id.name = "Name of File";
save.id.path = "Path of File";
save.id.enable = "1";

chrome.storage.sync.set(save, function() {
        console.log('Value is set to ' + save);
});

chrome.storage.sync.get(['save'], function(result) {
       console.log('Value currently is ' + result.value);
});
```

But its not working, how would I be able to search the ID and then pull the relevant data from that ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key you're writing is `'id'`, not `'save'`. The name of the variable doesn't matter to the API (it has no way of even knowing it). The important thing is the contents of the variable: it should be an object where each property name will be a key in the storage, and each property value will be the contents written under that key.

It means you can write multiple keys at once: `{key1: value1, key2: value2}`.

```js
// two separate entries will be written to the storage
chrome.storage.sync.set({
  id: {name: 'foo', path: 'bar', etc: ''},
  herp: 'derp',
}, () => {
  console.log('Value is set');
});
```

It also means you should read `'id'`, and the result variable will contain `id` as a property e.g. `result.id`, not just some abstract `result.value`.

You can also read multiple keys: `['key1', 'key2']` will produce a variable with two properties `{key1: value1, key2: value2}` each accessible as `result.key1` and `result.key2`.

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get(['id', 'herp'], result => {
  console.log('Got data:', result, 'id:', result.id, 'herp:', result.herp);
});
```

And don't use `+` in console.log because it won't serialize the contents of objects, instead use `,`.

See also:

- [How to inspect chrome.storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32435399/).
- [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2274242/)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you :D I also used JSON.parse to place the object so it can be stringify within the sync.set

Comment: Technically there's no need for JSON.parse/stringify because it's already done internally.