# How to get and set values in Chrome storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am learning JS these days and making a chrome extension. I want to store user data in chrome's storage API. And I want to ensure if the user has downloaded the extension for the first time then the variable should be 0 else change dynamically.

```
"use strict";

// chrome.storage.sync.clear()


chrome.storage.sync.get("totalviews",function(views){

    if (views.totalviews){
        console.log("There")

    }
    else{
        console.log("Not there")
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"totalviews":0})
        console.log("Done!!")

    }

})
```

However I am not able to update the variable to 0 if it does not exists. Any help?

Comment: Your code is fine so I guess you look in the [wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32471596).

Comment: Well if the code is correct then the console should log There however it logs Not there. Any help on that?

Comment: Nope, `if (0)` is false so the observed behavior is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Understood the logic behind it. I should have been updating the variable with 1 and 0