# Chrome Extension only works when popup is open

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a feature for an extension that has a checkbox, if the checkbox is checked the extension will stop collecting data, and if the checkbox is unchecked the extension will collect data. The feature works when the extension popup is open, and when I'm using the devtool. When the popup is closed and the checkbox is unchecked, it doesn't collect any data

I store the checkbox status in localstorage:

```
chrome.storage.local.set(
    {
      Privacy: document.getElementById("Privacy").checked,
    }
```

I call function to collect data if the checkbox is uncheck:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (activeInfo) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(["Privacy"], function (result) {
    if (result.Privacy != true || result.Privacy == null) {
      getTabInfo((activeTabId = activeInfo.tabId));
      console.log("inside privacy");
    } else {
      console.log("inside tabs.onActivated:");
      console.log("this is result.Privacy: ");
      console.log(result.Privacy);
    }
  });
})
```

I have tried : `result.Privacy == false`, that doesn't work either. I know its not collecting data because I don't see any data stored in the database.
This is a sample of my `manifest.json`:

```
"background": 
{
    "scripts": ["js/background.js", "js/firebase.js"],
    "persistent": true
},


"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "*://*/*",
        "storage",
        "identity"
    ],
```

Comment: 1) The popup's scripts run only when the popup is shown. 2) `chrome.storage.local` is not `localStorage` so you're looking in the wrong place, see [Inspect extension's chrome.storage in devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32435399)

Comment: use chrome.storage.sync instead

Comment: I changed it to chrome.storage.sync and still doesn't work. my extension only collects data when the popup is open

Comment: So chrome.tabs.onActivated is running in the background.js ? chrome.storage.local.set in popup.js / html? Will console.log(result) say something?

Comment: @JohanHoeksma there is no popup.js. I’m running everything in background.js

Comment: chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}, function() {
  console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
}); Did you try the callback at set