# localStorage is not defined in background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, service-worker

I am trying to get and set in my extension using background.js but whenever I run the extension I get the error saying that referenceError: localStorage is not defined.

whereas if I use it in my App.js , it is getting and setting in the local storage.

Note: I am using manifest v3

```
chrome.cookies.get(
      { url: "https://www.xxxx.com/", name: "abc" },
      async (cookie) => {
        const cookieValue: any = cookie?.value;
        oldJwtToken = localStorage.getItem("abc");
        console.log(cookieValue);
        console.log(oldJwtToken);
}
```

Comment: Service workers don't have access to localStorage. Switch to [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: I tried with chrome.storage.local but the set value is not fetching. I am getting undefined value.

Comment: Also a help :  Can u help me where to see the value stored when using chrome.storage.local.set() ?

Comment: It means you're not using it correctly. This API is asynchronous, see the examples.

Comment: chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
      chrome.storage.local.set({requestValue:request.message},()=>{
        console.log("Stored: " + request.message)
        sendResponse({processStatus:"Success",message:"yay!"})
      });
      return true;
    });

Comment: The code is correct. See [Inspect extension's chrome.storage in devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32435399)

Comment: This code is valid right? I have used the API docs snippets and coded. But the application->local storage of the service worker is empty. no value is getting stored, but the callback of the "set" function is getting called.

Comment: As I wrote in the comment, see [Inspect extension's chrome.storage in devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32435399).