# Access localStorage of chrome extension in background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I need to access the localStorage of a chrome extension in `background.js` to get values which have been set by the extension popup itself. The key-value pair is existing, I checked that by inspecting the extension popup.

However, reading from the localStorage by using the code below leads to an `undefined` result.

`background.js:`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        chrome.storage.local.get(['allowedSites'], function(result) {
            console.log('allowedSites: ', result.allowedSites);
        });
    }
);
```

The `storage` permission is set in v3 manifest. Any ideas what's wrong with this code?

Comment: chrome.storage.local is not `localStorage`, it's a different storage. See [Inspect extension's chrome.storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32435399)

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm! So no possibility to access ```localstorage``` from within ```background.js```?

Comment: No. Service worker can't access it. Don't use `localStorage`, switch to chrome.storage.local everywhere.