# Can't write and read from chrome.storage.local in popup, how to fix?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

**What i wanna achieve, from popup save data to local storage, then when next time i open the popup, in that for example input i got this values from local storage of popup window.**

**In manifest i added permission for "storage"**

From popup i tried this:

```
function updateStorage(data, callback){
    if(data){
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
            chrome.storage.local.set({ key: value }, callback);
        }   
    }
    return false;
}

function getFromStorage(storageElement, callback){
    if(storageElement){
        return chrome.storage.local.get(storageElement, callback);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in later code, i try to get `getFromStorage('myItem', result => {console.log(result)})`

Writing i make like this:

```
updateStorage({'myItem': 'almost secret data'}, _ => {console.log('test')})
```

But when i check the popup application then local storage, there is nothing.
When i reload page or re click on extension, i can't see the local storage item that i was write like 10s ago.

Comment: Replace the entire `for` loop with `chrome.storage.local.set(data, callback)`

Comment: @wOxxOm that not help save to local storage.

Comment: It's the correct solution, so I guess you're looking the wrong place. See [Inspect extension's chrome.storage in devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32435399)